# Scrolling Speed of GameObject increases unnecessarily

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I am facing a small problem. I start some spawns at a certain speed (let's say 2) and by time, the speed increases (let's say by 0.5). When the player loses and the Game Over screen is loaded, the speed continues to increase in the background, so when the player tries again, the speed isn't 2 (initial/normal) but it's 3 or 4 or (depending on how much time has passed).

How can I fix this? Should I destroy or disable the execution of the scripts when Gameover screen is loaded?

Code:

```
public class ObjectsScroller : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 2; // Speed of the rings
int MaxSpeed = 5; // Max speed of the rings

int timeSecond = 1; // 1s
float timer;

int sixSeconds = 6; // 6 seconds without subtraction
int countdown = 6; // Countdown with subtraction
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    speed = 2;
    timeSecond = 1;
    timer = Time.time;
    countdown = 6;
}

void Update()
{
    timer = Time.time;

    transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(timer >= timeSecond) { // Checks if a second passed
        countdown -= 1; // countdown decreases by one
        timeSecond += 1; // Increases so the loop runs again
    }

    if (countdown <= 0) { // Checks if countdown is less than 0
        speed += .5f; // Speed increases by 1
        transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        countdown = sixSeconds; // Countdown is equal to 8 Seconds so the loop runs again
    }

    if (speed >= 5) { // If speed is bigger or equal to 5 then make it 5 only
        speed = MaxSpeed;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: reset the spawn time back to 2 when the player restarts

Comment: well when he presses the restart button he is redirected back to game/play screen and in the script i intialized the speed to 2 in Start(). It doesn't work so any other suggestions?

Comment: make the speed variable public, when the player restarts find the gameobject, get the script component, and set the speed back to 2.

Comment: Well i did all what you said, but it just doesnt work.

Comment: Time.deltaTime is from when the application starts, maybe use a variable to log when the game starts (after death), and use Time.deltaTime - your variable.

Comment: Well, this might work but can you give me an example(code), am new to unity so...